Why does Solve solve for numerical values but not for symbolical values?
I have a complicated system of equations (see below) that I need to solve for $x[1], ..., x[20]$. The equations depend on three symbolical variables $a,b,c$.
If I replace just $c$ by a numerical value, say $c = \frac{2}{3}$ the equations gets solved, but if I leave $c$ to be symbolic Mathematica does not solve.
I.e. for
Solve[eqs /. c -> 2/3, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}]]

I get
{{x[1] -> (2400 a^2)/(31 a^2 + 600 b^2), [...]

but for
Solve[eqs, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}]]

I get
{}

I can also type other values for $c$ and it works, so clearly the system of equations must be solvable. What's going wrong here?
The system of equations is
eqs = {((31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (115 a x[1] + 
       4 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
       4 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[9] - 
       40 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]))/(36000 a^3) == 2, 
   Sqrt[6] a^2 Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17] == 
    10 b (25 a x[1] + Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
       Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[9] - 
       10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]), (
    a (10 Sqrt[6] a b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17] + 
       10 b c (-Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[10] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[12] + 60 b x[18]) + 
       a^2 (-25 x[1] + 31 c x[18])))/3750 == 
    1/900 (a^2 + 24 b^2) (25 a x[1] + 
       Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
       Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[9] - 
       10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]), 
   4 a^3 (-18000 c - 775 x[8] + 961 c^2 x[8]) + 
     2400 b^2 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) + 
     10 a b (115 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c x[1] + 
        124 c^2 (60 b x[8] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19]) + 
        100 (-60 b x[8] + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19])) == 
    5 a^2 (23 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] - 
       248 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9])), 
   10 a^2 b (25 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] - 
       310 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) + 
       6 c Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) == 
    6000 b^3 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) + 
     a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (310 b x[8] - 
        Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19]) + 
     100 a b^2 (25 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c x[1] + 
        31 c^2 (60 b x[8] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19]) + 
        25 (-60 b x[8] + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19])), 
   5 a (5 a Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] - 
       2 Sqrt[6]
         b c (25 Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[1] + 
          a Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (31 x[7] + 25 x[9] - 6 x[11])) + 
       50 b (60 b x[8] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[19]) + 
       2 b c^2 (-60 b (31 x[8] + 6 x[10] - 6 x[12]) + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] (6 x[18] + 31 x[19]))) == 
    a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (25 x[8] + 6 x[15]) + 
     600 b^2 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]), -(c/
     6) == ((31 a^2 + 
       600 b^2) (10 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[7] - 25 a x[15] + 
       31 a c^2 x[15]))/(225000 a^3), 
   a^3 (-775 x[1] + c^2 (-9000 + 961 x[1])) + 
     600 b^2 (-1 + c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)]
       x[7] + a^2 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 
         31 c^2)] (-31 c x[5] - 25 x[7] + 31 c^2 x[7]) + 
     10 a b (-25 + 31 c^2) (60 b x[1] + 
        Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] (x[4] + c (x[12] + x[15]))) == 
    0, 4 a^3 (-18000 c - 775 x[10] + 961 c^2 x[10]) + 
     2400 b^2 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) + 
     10 a b (115 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c x[1] + 
        124 c^2 (60 b x[10] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18]) + 
        100 (-60 b x[10] + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18])) == 
    5 a^2 (23 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] - 
       248 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9])), 
   10 a^2 b (25 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] - 
       310 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) + 
       6 c Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) == 
    6000 b^3 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]) + 
     a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (310 b x[10] - 
        Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18]) + 
     100 a b^2 (25 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c x[1] + 
        31 c^2 (60 b x[10] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18]) + 
        25 (-60 b x[10] + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18])), 
   a (25 (a Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[2] + 
          10 b (60 b x[10] - Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[18])) - 
       10 b c^2 (60 b (6 x[8] + 31 x[10] - 6 x[13]) - 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] (31 x[18] + 6 x[19])) + 
       c (-10 Sqrt[6]
            b (25 Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[1] + 
             a Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (31 x[7] + 25 x[9] - 6 x[11])) + 
          6 a Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[20])) == 
    a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (25 x[10] + 6 x[16]) + 
     600 b^2 c (10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[7] + x[9]) - 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[17]), -(c/
     6) == ((31 a^2 + 
       600 b^2) (10 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[7] - 25 a x[16] + 
       31 a c^2 x[16] - 
       c Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[20]))/(
    225000 a^3), 
   a^3 (-775 x[1] + c^2 (-9000 + 961 x[1])) + 
     10 a b (60 b (-25 + 31 c^2) x[1] + 
        Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2]
          c (31 c x[4] - 25 x[12] + 6 x[15] + 
           31 c^2 (x[12] + x[15]) - 31 x[16])) + 
     600 b^2 ((-1 + c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)]
          x[7] + 10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[20]) + 
     a^2 (-31 c Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[5] - 
        25 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
        31 c^2 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
        310 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[20]) == 0, (1/
    45000)(-4 a^2 (575 Sqrt[6] b c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[2] + 
         25 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] (x[7] - x[11]) - 
         31 c^2 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] (x[7] - 
            x[11])) + 
      a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (115 x[1] - 115 x[3] + 124 c x[14]) + 
      2400 b^2 c^2 (Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
         Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[9] - 
         10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]) - 
      40 a b c (-1725 b c x[1] + 
         25 (Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[8] + 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[10] - 
            60 b (x[18] + x[19])) - 
         31 c^2 (Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[8] + 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[10] - 
            60 b (x[18] + x[19])))) == (8 a^3 c^2)/5, 
   c^2/25 == 
    1/6 (1 - c^2) + ((31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2) (115 a x[1] + 
        4 Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7]))/(
     5400000 a^3), (1/(
    135000 a^3))(31 a^2 + 
       600 b^2) (600 Sqrt[6] b^2 c Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (-1 + c^2) x[7] +
        Sqrt[6] a^2 (25 - 31 c^2)^(3/2) (x[5] - c x[7]) + 
       a (-25 + 
          31 c^2) (c (Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[1] + 
             60 b x[4]) - 60 b x[12] + 60 b c^2 (x[12] + x[15]))) == 
    4 b c^3, 
   600 b^2 c^2 (Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] + 
        Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[9] - 
        10 Sqrt[6] b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]) + 
     a^3 (-25 + 31 c^2) (25 x[1] - 25 x[3] + 25 c x[14] - 6 c x[18] - 
        6 c x[19]) == 
    a (25 a Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] (x[7] - x[11]) + 
       c^2 (-15000 b^2 x[1] + 
          31 a Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] (-x[7] + 
             x[11]) + 60 Sqrt[6] a b Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[17]) + 
       250 b c (2 Sqrt[6] a Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[2] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[8] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[10] - 60 b x[18] - 
          60 b x[19]) - 
       310 b c^3 (Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[8] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] x[10] - 
          60 b (x[18] + x[19]))), 
   25 a x[1] + Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7] == 0, 
   5 a^3 (-775 x[1] + c^2 (-9000 + 961 x[1])) + 
     600 b^2 (5 (-1 + c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)]
          x[7] + 12 Sqrt[6] b c^2 Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[20]) + 
     a^2 (5 (-25 + 31 c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)]
          x[7] + 372 Sqrt[6] b c^2 Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] x[20]) == 
    12 a b (-25 + 31 c^2) (-250 b x[1] + 
       Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c (x[13] + x[16])), 
   5 (a^3 (-775 x[1] + c^2 (-9000 + 961 x[1])) + 
       600 b^2 (-1 + c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)]
         x[7] + a^2 (-25 + 
          31 c^2) Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[7]) == 
    12 a b (-25 + 31 c^2) (-250 b x[1] + 
       Sqrt[6] Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] c (x[12] + x[15])), 
   5 Sqrt[6] a^2 Sqrt[25 - 31 c^2] (x[5] - x[6]) == 
    12 b (a (25 c x[4] + 25 (-x[12] + x[13]) + 
          31 c^2 (x[12] - x[13] + x[15] - x[16])) + 
       c Sqrt[-(31 a^2 + 600 b^2) (-25 + 31 c^2)] x[20])};

(I have to add some more text, so that the website let's me post this question:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.)

Solve assumes the parameters take generic values. It seems there is no solution for generic value of $c$. For example, both Solve[eqs /. c -> 0, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}]] and Solve[eqs /. c -> 1, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}]] return {}.

Thanks. So how can I specify a particular range of $c$ so that I can get the solution?

Theoretically something like Solve[Flatten@{eqs, c > 0}, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}]] or, if you want Mathematica to figure out the conditions, Solve[eqs, Table[x[j], {j, 1, 20}], MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]. However, both run for minutes and use several GB of memory before I run out of patience and kill them.

OK, I let it run a few minutes more and now it's up to 16GB. I don't think you'll be able to use this solution, if it ever finishes.

If all the equation were polynomials, then you can find for which $c$ there is a solution using Eliminate other variables. I think you should start by simplifying these equations: say, replace Sqrt[31 a^2 + 600 b^2] by another symbol.

Dimensions[eqs] results in {21}. You deal with a system of 21 linear equations in 20 unknowns.
